# How to add PPT notes using docx4j

Tags: java, powerpoint, docx4j

I am creating PPT files using the library docx4j. I have been able to create slides with text and images, but I have not been able to add notes to them.

I am creating the slide like this:

```
MainPresentationPart pp = (MainPresentationPart)presentationParts.get(new PartName("/ppt/presentation.xml"));
SlideLayoutPart layoutPart = (SlideLayoutPart)presentationParts.get(new PartName("/ppt/slideLayouts/slideLayout1.xml"));
SlidePart slidePart = PresentationMLPackage.createSlidePart(pp, layoutPart, new PartName("/ppt/slides/slide" + ++slideNumber + ".xml"));
```

so I can add text or images to the body, but when I  try to access the field slidePart.notes it is null. I have tried to initialize it

```
slidePart.setPartShortcut(new NotesSlidePart());
```

but then everything inside notes is null and I have not achieved anything.

So, does anyone have a working example of how to add notes to a PPT file?

Many thanks

Comment: Guito, can you please provide some samples where you have added text and images, I am finding it really hard to understand and there are no good tutorials. :(

Comment: @ItiTyagi I'm sorry, but I don't have any example anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not enough to do:

```
slidePart.setPartShortcut(new NotesSlidePart());
```

You need to explicitly add the notes slide part to your slide part (so that the relationships get set up correctly), by invoking addTargetPart.

But there's more you have to do given the way the pptx format works.  To see what parts are required, upload a pptx to the docx4j webapp.  Here's the code I wrote just now based on doing that:

```
    // Now add notes slide.
    // 1. Notes master
    NotesMasterPart nmp = new NotesMasterPart();
    NotesMaster notesmaster = (NotesMaster)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(notesMasterXml, Context.jcPML);
    nmp.setJaxbElement(notesmaster);
    // .. connect it to /ppt/presentation.xml
    Relationship ppRelNmp = pp.addTargetPart(nmp);
    /*
     *  <p:notesMasterIdLst>
            <p:notesMasterId r:id="rId3"/>
        </p:notesMasterIdLst>
     */
    pp.getJaxbElement().setNotesMasterIdLst(createNotesMasterIdListPlusEntry(ppRelNmp.getId()));

    // .. NotesMasterPart typically has a rel to a theme 
    // .. can we get away without it? 
    // Nope .. read this in from a file
    ThemePart themePart = new ThemePart(new PartName("/ppt/theme/theme2.xml"));
        // TODO: read it from a string instead
    themePart.unmarshal(
            FileUtils.openInputStream(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/theme2.xml"))
        );      
    nmp.addTargetPart(themePart);

    // 2. Notes slide
    NotesSlidePart nsp = new NotesSlidePart();
    Notes notes = (Notes)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(notesXML, Context.jcPML);
    nsp.setJaxbElement(notes);
    // .. connect it to the slide
    slidePart.addTargetPart(nsp);
    // .. it also has a rel to the slide
    nsp.addTargetPart(slidePart);
    // .. and the slide master
    nsp.addTargetPart(nmp);
```

You can find the complete example at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/samples/pptx4j/org/pptx4j/samples/SlideNotes.java

Comment: Thank you very much. Tomorrow I will try it! :)

Comment: It worked perfectly. As I wanted various notes I initialized the NotesSlidePart like this:
    NotesSlidePart nsp = new NotesSlidePart("note" + slideNumber + ".xml");


I also tried to do it without the Notes Master and it worked. Is it just good practice to add it?